# how to populate store with recursive object extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, recursion, tree

I have an object with this structure

first
last 
uid
id
rels[]

Rels is an array that contains again objects with the same structure.
how can i manage this object in way to populate a treeStore using extjs in the load? i need to maintain the hierarchy between parent and childs

example 
parent
 
    child1
    child2
         nephew1 
         nephew2

and so on. they are all under the parent node.

any suggestion? i tried in several way using recursive function but without results.

This is my code (not working)

```
Ext.define('utenti', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'F',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'L',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'Uid',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'Id',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]
});

var TreeUserStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'utenti',
    root: {
        text: 'Root',
        //id: 'Radice_utenti',
        expanded: true
    },
    listeners: {

        load: function eachRecursive(ResObj) {
            var childNode;
            if (ResObj.Rels.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.Rels.length; i++) {
                    eachRecursive(ResObj.Rels[i]);

                }
            } else {
                childNode = Ext.create('utenti', {
                    F: ResObj.F,
                    L: ResObj.L,
                    Uid: ResObj.Uid,
                    Id: ResObj.Id
                });
                TreeUserStore.appendChild(child);
            }
        }
    }


});
```

I found the function that extract the data from the object

```
function eachRecursive(ResObj, parent) {

    if (ResObj.Rels.length > 0) {

        var childNodeModel = {
            name: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            text: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            leaf: false,
            children: []
        };

        alert("padre:" + parent.name + ", figlio:" + childNodeModel.name);
        parent.children.push(childNodeModel);

        for (var i = 0; i < ResObj.Rels.length; i++) {
            eachRecursive(ResObj.Rels[i], childNodeModel);
        }
    } else {
        var childNodeModel = {
            name: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            text: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            leaf: true
        };
        alert("padre:" + parent.name + ", figlio:" + childNodeModel.name);
        parent.children.push(childNodeModel);

    }

}
```

But at the moment I'm not able to show in the `TreePanel` the elements. I tried to use appendChild but without any results, i also tried to create TreeNode but it gives me and `error` such as `object is not a function`.

How can i do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `appendChild` node's method for adding child node to hierarchy.

Your recursive function so should look like this:

```
function eachRecursive(ResObj, parent) {

    if (ResObj.Rels.length > 0) {

        var childNodeModel = {
            name: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            text: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            leaf: false,
            children: []
        };

        var childNode = parent.appendChild(childNodeModel);

        for (var i = 0; i < ResObj.Rels.length; i++) {
            eachRecursive(ResObj.Rels[i], childNode);
        }
    } else {
        var childNodeModel = {
            name: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            text: ResObj.F + " " + ResObj.L,
            leaf: true
        };
        parent.appendChild(childNodeModel);

    }
}
```

And you start populating store from root:

```
eachRecursive(data, TreeUserStore.getRootNode());
```

Comment: thank you akatum, it works perfectly! 
i have only made few little changes:
in the function i declared the variable childNode as "var childNode" because otherwise all the childs after a parent would be placed under it, loosing its real parent (i don't know if it's clear..). The other changed is the call, i used 
eachRecursive(data, TreeUser.getRootNode());

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I mistakenly declared variable as global, I've fixed this in answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Ext.override(Ext.data.TreeStore, {
>             appendChildRecusive: function (nodeTarget, itemsJson) {
>                 for (i in itemsJson) {
>                     var newNode = nodeTarget.createNode(itemsJson[i]);
>
>                     if (i != 'hasObject')
>                         nodeTarget.appendChild(newNode);
>
>                     if (itemsJson[i].children != undefined)
>                         this.appendChildRecusive(newNode, itemsJson[i].children);
>                 }
>             }
>         });
> ```